# How to allow only the members of a facebook group login into my website using facebook Authentication API?

Tags: authentication, facebook-login

Can someone please give me the API code or tell me how to allow only the members of a certain group on facebook login into my website using Facebook login Authentication API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the login with the Authentication, then you can query the `group_member` FQL table to see if they exist in there for the group's id.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/group_member/

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api

Comment: As of 4/26/2015, this is outdated. Migrate to Graph API